# Label + Description for Main Select Element using Angular-Formly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I am using http://angular-formly.com/ and I am stuck at adding description under the label of Select dropdown.

```
app.controller('CalcCtrl', function CalcCtrl(formlyVersion, formlyValidationMessages) {
var vm = this;
// function assignment
vm.onSubmit = onSubmit;

// variable assignment
vm.model = {

};

vm.fields = [

  {
    key: 'am_quant_lg',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {
      required: true,
      label: 'Large',
      description: 'Description of my input field is here',
      type: 'number',
      max: '100',
      maxMessage: 'test ',
    },
  },
  {
    key: 'House_type',
    type: 'select',
    templateOptions: {
      required: true,
      label: 'What type of House you need?',
      options: [{
          name: 'Townhouse',
          value: 1,
        },
        {
          name: 'Single',
          value: 2,
        },]
      },
  },
```

So i need to display some description under the label 'What type of house you need? Maybe a few lines. I know how to add description to input text field as you can see above. I know how to add description to other options as well. Just need help for the main Select element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently not in documentation but you can still add it the same way;

```
  {
key: 'House_type',
type: 'select',
templateOptions: {
  required: true,
  label: 'What type of House you need?',
  description: 'Description goes here?',
  options: [{
      name: 'Townhouse',
      value: 1,
    },
    {
      name: 'Single',
      value: 2,
    },]
  },
```